# popup menu is hiding its parent text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a popup menu that shows/hides when a div is hovered over. The menu showing/hiding works fine. However, the div has the text "Square" in it that disappears when I add the menu to it in the code.

**index.html**

```
<div id= "squareDiv" style="width: 100px; height:100px; border:2px solid #a1a1a1;" >
  Square
</div>
```

**my JS**

```
//Add list items to the div
$("#squareDiv").html(
  "<ul class='list_menu'><li><a href='firefox.com'>Maya Agriculture</a></li>"+
  "<li><a href='firefox.com'>Maya Agriculture Crossword</a></li>"+
  "<li><a href='firefox.com'>Inca Agriculture</a></li>"+
  "<li><a href='firefox.com'>Inca Agriculture Crossword</a></li>"+
  "</ul>"
);

$("#squareDiv").hover(function () {
  $('ul.list_menu').slideDown('medium',function() {
    $(this).clearQueue();
  });
}, function () {
  $('ul.list_menu').slideUp('medium',function() {
    $(this).clearQueue();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `append(...)` instead of `html(...)`, `html()` replaces content

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!